# VK error no access_token passed when get list of friends

Tags: django, vk

My app registers a user using Vkontakte and displays his name and a list of 5 friends, the name is displayed, but when trying to get friends, it outputs an error:

```
access_token '******'
code    '*****'
data    
{'error': {'error_code': 5,
           'error_msg': 'User authorization failed: no access_token passed.',
           'request_params': [{'key': 'order', 'value': 'random'},
                              {'key': 'count', 'value': '5'},
                              {'key': '                                    '
                                      'access_token',
                               'value': '*****'},
                              {'key': 'v', 'value': '5.103'},
                              {'key': 'method', 'value': 'friends.get'},
                              {'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'}]}}
first_name  'Марсель'
greeting_string 'Здравствуйте, Марсель Абдуллин, вы авторизованы. <br>'
last_name   'Абдуллин'
r   <Response [200]>
request_link    
('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?order=random&count=5&                                    '
 'access_token=*****&v=5.103')
user_id 224454327
```

Line with error:

```
array_of_friends_ID = data['response']['items']
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not in english

Comment: Please ask the question in *English*, or at [ru.SO].

Comment: oh sorry, i fixed it

Comment: I would say that the error occurs before that line, as the error message seems to indicate that no access_token was passed in the request.   Please provide the code that does the request and accepts the response.

Comment: I solved the problem, it was because i split stroke with request link